# Combining data from cells

Tags: excel

How do I combine the data in columns A and B, into just column A with a space between the data. If there is a way to add the `mg` after that would be great. So:

[image]

becomes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to use the concatenation operator `&`.  In the screenshot below, into cell `D2` I have entered the following formula:

```
=A2&" "B2&" mg"
```

As you can see, this results in the output:

```
Pork 708 mg
```

You can copy this formula down the entire column to cover all rows of your data.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awesome.

Comment: Says I can in 1 min, will do!

Comment: Here is another way to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75468486/5091720

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function.

> Use CONCATENATE, one of the text functions, to join two or more text strings into one string.
>
> Syntax: CONCATENATE(text1, [text2], ...)

Text values van be cell references or your desired text, such as spaces or mg.